# C# - Settings.Default.Save() is very slow

Tags: c#, save, settings

I want to save some UI changes when the program closes. I've read that one of the simplest ways to do that is with settings. I figured I'd save those changes to the settings whenever the program closes, instead of saving it everytime the user changes those settings. So, I have this:

```
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    { 
        Properties.Settings.Default.PostProcessSubs = checkBox_PPSubs.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Which just saves whether that checkbox is on or off by default. However, when I have this, the application hangs for a second or two when I press X to close it. If I comment out the save() command, it closes ok, but of course the changes aren't saved. Besides this, everything works ok, so I find it quite strange that this process is so slow.

BTW, my settings aren't bloated or anything, I only have two booleans and two small strings in there.

Edit: This only happens when run trough Start Without Debugging. Running trough debug or trough release works OK. Quite strange still.

Edit2: no,still happens. Slow as hell.

Comment: Have you checked the location of the settings file that it saves?  Is it on a network drive or some slower media like that?

Comment: Perhaps the CLR is jitting some code. If you do a second save in the same run of the program, is it faster or not?

Comment: XML serialization is none too fast, but there isn't any scenario where it can cost 4 billion cpu cycles when you do it repeatedly.  This is an environmental problem.  The 90% case is the crapware that programmers voluntarily install on their machine, the kind that always gets its underwear in a bundle on any xml file.  Disable your anti-malware and try again.  And do consider only saving when your program terminates, saving at the very moment the setting changes is dangerous.  If the change causes your program to bomb then you'll have good odds that it will bomb forever.

Comment: Well, I discovered that it works ok when Run in Debug mode, and in if I compile it in Release mode. However, if I run it trough Start Without Debugging (which was what I was doing), that's only then that the problem happens. 
The location of the file is OK, and the second run is the same.

It works ok, but why the hell should Start Without Debugging make this slower?

Comment: For it to be _slower_ when you run without the debugger doesn't make any sense. Is it also slow if you run the debug build straight from Windows (i.e. don't even use Visual Studio at all to start it)? Saving your settings should always be very fast; even 1000 ms is crazy slow and points to some kind of problem on your computer (maybe some malware that remains inactive if it detects a debugger running?).

Comment: Now it also craps out even with the debugger. Supposedly I don't have any malware.

I've run the CPU profiler, and it seems that System.Xml.ni.dll is calling itself 47% of the time. It's also calling System.Configuration.ni.dll which is equally calling itself constantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I solved this and I feel retarded. But here's a pointer if someone has a similar problem.
So, what was happening was my config file was 16 MB. Why? Well, one of the configs was the path of an executable. However, the code I used for that executable was not correct, as I had copied it without thinking from other part of my program. I had this... it's sad

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.ProgramPath = 
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
```

When obviously it should have just been

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.ProgramPath = 
openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
```

Of course, the original code I had was converting the entire executable into text, and saving it into the config file. The config file got bloated, and even if I didn't use that part of the code anymore, the config file was already bloated. So, whenever I saved any other configuration, instead of saving a few KB file, it was saving a 16 MB file. Everytime. So, yeah...

TLDR: Check your config file size... might be bloated for some reason.